# call function in vb.net vs 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have Form1 and Form2. I want call function in Form1 from Form2
but it is not working. I use Visual Studio 2015.

```
Public Class Form1
Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim form As New Form2
    form.Show()
End Sub

Public Sub Test()
    TextBox1.Text = "Hello"
End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim form As New Form1
    form.Test()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The problem is that you are creating a new instance of `Form1` and calling the method on that. If you have a TV at home, would expect buying a new TV and changing the channel on that to affect your existing TV? This is exactly the same. You need to call the method on the existing instance. If `Form1` is the startup form then it will be the default instance of its type, so you could use that. Otherwise, `Form1` must pass a self-reference, i.e. `Me`, to `Form2` when it creates it.

Comment: i am sorry, i not understand, what can i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is going on is you are creating another `Form1` with your button click in `Form2` it is not your parent form. You need to assign `Form2`'s Owner when you create it, then you can reference back to it. Something like this:

**Form1:**

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim form As New Form2
        form.Show(Me) 'I am assigning Form2's Owner here
    End Sub

    Public Sub Test()
        TextBox1.Text = "Hello"
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Form2**

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        CType(Me.Owner, Form1).Test() 'Casting Form2's Owner to Form1 to access your sub

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This solution will have (most likely) unwanted side-effects. An owned form behaves in a specific way and if the OP doesn't want `Fomr2` to behave that way then this solution will break their app. A more general solution should be provided where `Form2` has a field/property of type `Form1` that can be set directly or via a constructor or method argument.

Comment: @jmcilhinney have used this in the past, for what he is trying to do here, it should work, his other option is to pass it in the constructor or a sub as you mentioned.

Comment: I agree that it will allow the OP to achieve their specific aim of calling a method on `Form1` but it's not the best general solution because it has side-effects that will likely trip them up if they try to use this in a less contrived situation. "You need to assign Form2's Owner when you create it". That is not a true statement. That's just one way to get a reference to the correct `Form1` instance into `Form2` and not the best one unless you want an owned form.